# How to run same async function multiple times concurrent?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

**Setup:**

So I have a *clients array* consisting of *client objects*. Also two async functions, one them is processing the incoming messages from a WebSocket and the other one is executing some API calls with the given *client object*.

When a certain message arrives from the WebSocket connection, *function_a* should detect it and start a *for loop* in the *clients array*. For each *client object* in the *clients array* I want to trigger *function_b*. But the *function_b* should run concurrent for the each *client*.

**Example Code:**

```
clients = {}

async def function_a(ws_message): # this is being called each time when a new message arrives
    if ws_message == 'signal_message':
        for client in clients:
             await function_b(client)

async def function_b(client):
    # get client parameters
    # make an API request with those parameters
```

**UPDATE || Code with *asyncio.gather()***

So I have updated my actual code with *asyncio.gather()* but there is still ~500 ms delay between each function task. I am not sure but I guess this is because my *function_b* has some non-async blocking code thanks to *requests* library.

```
clients = {}
tasks = []

async def function_a(ws_message): 
    if ws_message == 'signal_message':
        for client in clients:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(function_b(client))
            tasks.append(task)
    if tasks:
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

async def function_b(client):
    # get client parameters
    # make an API request with those parameters
```

As I said this doesn't work either.

**Issue:**

Right now the *function_b* gets triggered without any issue, however *function_b* runs about 500ms and the await calls from the *function_a* waits for the one before it to finish. So for example the *function_b* process for the second *client object* in the *clients array* takes ~1000ms to finish after the WebSocket message has received. And this delay gets bigger with the each call obviously.

**Solution?**

Have can fix this so the each *function_b* process can run concurrently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does function b has `await` pauses in its code? If it is synchronous, asyncio can't run it in parallel.

Comment: @jsbueno No it doesn't have any `asyncio.sleep()` or `time.sleep()` in it. Only thing that is synchronous it has are the API calls which are handled by request module. Right now I'm converting to aiohttp instead of request to see if it makes any difference at all.

Answer (score 4):

To launch code in parallel from within a co-routine, you have to create a "task" with it (and pause, without necessarily awaiting for the task).

The [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) call does the wrapping, calls, execution, and wraps
the return values all in one go:

```
clients = {}

async def function_a(ws_message): # this is being called each time when a new message arrives
    if ws_message == 'signal_message':
        await asyncio.gather(*(function_b(client) for client in clients))
```

Full example on the interactive prompt:

```
In [8]: import asyncio

In [9]: async def coro1():
   ...:     await asyncio.sleep(1)
   ...:     print("step 1")
   ...:     await asyncio.sleep(1)
   ...:     print("step 2")
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [10]: async def coro2():
    ...:     await asyncio.gather(*(coro1() for i in range(5)))
    ...: 

In [11]: asyncio.run(coro2())
step 1
step 1
step 1
step 1
step 1
step 2
step 2
step 2
step 2
step 2
```

As can be seen, all co-routines run in parallel, outputing the result of the first print, and after 1s, the output of the second print call is shown.

If no parallelism is observe it may be due to the co-routine you not yielding the execution to the main loop by itself awaiting other co-routines. For CPU bound code, one can only achieve parallelism by running the functions in different threads or processes.

Comment: Well I have tried your solution but it didn't help at all. It still executes functions one by one.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: It does not do anything. It takes the same time as normal function does. It does not call the function concurrently.